# Why is only one component appearing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, flowlayout

I have a JFrame and for some reason only one component is appearing

```
public JFrame mainMenuFrame = new JFrame();
    public JLabel welcomeText1 = new JLabel();
    public JLabel welcomeText2 = new JLabel("What would you like to do?");

    public void mainMenuWindow() {
        
        setNameFrame.dispose();
        
        welcomeText1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        welcomeText1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        welcomeText1.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
        welcomeText1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        
        welcomeText2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        welcomeText2.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        welcomeText2.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        welcomeText2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        
        mainMenuFrame.add(welcomeText1);
        mainMenuFrame.add(welcomeText2);
        mainMenuFrame.revalidate();
        mainMenuFrame.repaint();

        mainMenuFrame.setTitle(game);
        mainMenuFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        mainMenuFrame.getContentPane();
        mainMenuFrame.pack();
        mainMenuFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainMenuFrame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
        mainMenuFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainMenuFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainMenuFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

I have tried changing the component type but it seems it will only display one component

Comment: check the documentation of JFrame and, in special, of [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/BorderLayout.html): "Each region may contain no more than one component" (and since no component is specified when the components are added, the default `CENTER` is used)

Comment: 1) Layout managers should be set BEFORE you add components to a panel. 2) There is no need for the revalidate() and repaint() statements. Those statements are only needed if you add components to a visible frame.

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

Specify your layout manager *before* adding components.

### Mind your layout manager

To recap the Comments:

- Every new [`JFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFrame.html) defaults to using [`BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) as its [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).
- `BorderLayout` contains a limit of one *single* component in each of its five regions.
- You added a component multiple times. Given that `BorderLayout` contains at most one component in a region, successive `add` calls replace the previous component with the next component.

In this example, the `two` component replaces the previously added `one` component. We added two components, but only see one.

```java
package work.basil.example.swing;

import javax.swing.*;

public class OneComponent
{
    private static void createAndShowGUI ( )
    {
        // Window
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated ( true );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame ( "Adding Components In Swing" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        // Widgets
        JLabel one = new JLabel ( "One" );
        JLabel two = new JLabel ( "Two" );

        // Arrange
        frame.getContentPane ( ).add ( one );
        frame.getContentPane ( ).add ( two );

        // Display.
        frame.pack ( );
        frame.setVisible ( true );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater ( new Runnable ( )
        {
            public void run ( ) { OneComponent.createAndShowGUI ( ); }
        } );
    }
}
```

The solution is to specify your desired layout manager *before* adding widgets.

In our revised example, up top we specify a [`FlowLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/FlowLayout.html) rather than go with the default `BorderLayout`. Only after setting the layout manager do we add any components.

Now when run we now see both added components, the second flowing after the first as expected with a `FlowLayout`.

Tip: Organize your code in three or four sections: Window/JFrame, Content/Widgets, and Arrange/Display.

```java
package work.basil.example.swing;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class OneComponent
{
    private static void createAndShowGUI ( )
    {
        // Window
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated ( true );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame ( "Adding Components In Swing" );
        frame.setLayout ( new FlowLayout ( ) );  // ⬅️ Specify desired layout manager, to replace default `BorderLayout`. 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        // Widgets
        JLabel one = new JLabel ( "One" );
        JLabel two = new JLabel ( "Two" );

        // Arrange
        frame.getContentPane ( ).add ( one );
        frame.getContentPane ( ).add ( two );

        // Display.
        frame.pack ( );
        frame.setVisible ( true );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater ( new Runnable ( )
        {
            public void run ( ) { OneComponent.createAndShowGUI ( ); }
        } );
    }
}
```

---

(Running in Java 21.)

Comment: Adding all those weird extra spaces makes the coder harder to read, not easier.

Comment: @DavidConrad Iseewhatyoumean.Somucheasiertoreadifwejusteliminatethespaces.

Comment: Obviously I mean like `frame.getContentPane().add(one);` as you would see in the JDK source code, Effective Java by Josh Bloch, or pretty much any Java style guide.